# How can Apache IoTDB retain two decimal places of average value after query aggregation?

Tags: average, mean, apache-iotdb, iotdb

After query aggregation in Apache IoTDB, can average calculate `avg` retain two decimal places in IoTDB? If this can be done, what settings should I install? If this cannot be done, are there any other ways in IoTDB to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`String` type comparison is currently not supported in Apache IoTDB. If necessary to do the scenario you mentioned, you can customize an UDF function in IoTDB. Detailed steps can be found in the official guide.